# I want to fix the image not being cut

Tags: html, css, image

I want to make a quote part with owl carousel, and this is my code:

```
<div class="carousel-item overflow-hidden position-relative" data-bs-interval="10000">
                    <div class="position-relative border border-primary">
                      <img src="{{ asset('image/quote_frame.png')}}" class="w-100" alt="banner1" style="height: 300px; object-fit: cover; opacity:0.8"/>
                      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block text-dark" style="width:80%; position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%);">
                        <p>Some text here</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="position-absolute" style="top: -30px; left: 15px;">
                      <img src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/Avatars/img%20(1).webp"
                        class="rounded-circle shadow-2" alt="woman avatar" width="100"
                        height="100">
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

I expected the image would on the top and have high z-index to show. But it stop at the range of the top like this picture:
[image]

What is the problem? And how can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. How are people supposed to help you when you don't provide the CSS going with the HTML?

Comment: There is overlflow hidden in owl carousel class. Try to play with that and check.